# Rule via SQL rule query statement that can take an action if the temperature is more than 15% higher than the average of all other devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Is it possible to create a rule via SQL rule query statement that can take an action if the temperature is more than 15% higher than the average of all other devices. Or do we need to use other AWS service like AWS Lambda to achieve this? Just trying to get an advice on how approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IoT SQL rule would only be applied to the current event payload. Think of it like a way to filter events instead of a way to query a database. It would not have access to the "average of all other devices" value. You would need to build that yourself, possibly by storing all the device values in DynamoDB and calculating the average in a Lambda function.